# Conditional Median combining different values in Google Sheet Formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is there a way to calculate the Median of a set of values in one column depending on whether the  adjacent column contains a value that is within a set of values?

Below is a table sample:

[image: Sheet table]

I would like to get the median of all the Revenues from the US (combine Team US East and West).

Answer (score 2):

First you have to filter this table according to your criteria and then extract median from new range.

Filtering may be obtained using QUERY function, and then you use built in MEDIAN formula.

I've prepared my example which uses two conditions - like yours.

```
=median(query(B2:C11,"select B where C ='a' or C='b'"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is with Filter and Regexmatch:

```
=median(filter(B2:B,regexmatch(C2:C,"^Team US")))
```

or in case there are more teams like Team US North and you don't want to include them:

```
=median(filter(B2:B,regexmatch(C2:C,"^Team US East|^Team US West")))
```

[image]